# How to get send gzip content as PHP response

Tags: php

my ajax response is very large its actually 900kb. so I need to gzip to improve the performance.

can anyone please help me to get gziped content from my php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Before outputing anything on the page throw in this:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

Then after your content follow it up with:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

And your content will be gzipped

Comment: As ra_htial mentioned it is preferred to use `zlib.output_compression` rather than `ob_gzhandler`, as php.net docs recommend either, moreover do not forget to use `ob_end_flush();` at the end of output.

Comment: zlib would also work, but it will compress all of the requests on that site so long as the browser supports it. While that may be ideal in most cases this was a question to address the ajax response size.

Answer (score 16):

**Option 1:**

configure `zlib.output_compression` in your `php.ini`

Doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression

**Option 2:**

Use : `ob_gzhandler`

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

**Note:**

`900Kb` is too much for an ajax response.

Comment: +1 to 900Kb being too big for AJAX. It'll work, but you should probably try rethinking your delivery mechanism.

Comment: Yes now I reduced to 300kb. And again I used Chausser's idea and got 93.7kb of size. Now its working great.

Answer (score 13):

If you cannot update your `php.ini` config file before using `ob_gzhandler()` you could try this too:

```
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 1);
```

Comment: This is the best answer. It does not require checking that the zlib extension is installed.

Comment: From within any PHP file using: `ob_start('ob_gzhandler');`  and `ob_end_flush();`  will only compress that particular buffer/page, and it must not affect anything else served by PHP. Whereas `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 1);` in PHP file. Or `zlib.output_compression = On` in the `PHP.ini` file, it will use this compression for every response you have in your PHP project, unless you change it with `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 1);`

Comment: Also, you can change the compression level (ratio) by setting `zlib.output_compression_level`  by specifying a value between `0` (**no compression**) to `9` (**most compression**). The **default value is** `-1`, *lets the server decide which level to use*. Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression-level