# PHP: Echo raw JSON data instead of stringified version

Tags: php, json, ajax, performance

I'm working on a webpage that sends AJAX-requests to a server to get some JSON back. In the .php-file, I simply echo the array with:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

As far as I know, this sends back text that *represents* a JSON object. **Are there more efficient ways (data wise) of doing this?**

Boiled down, what I mean is: If I wanna send the number *53.52598895*, I could do this in string format and use up a bunch of bytes, or I could send just a few bytes representing the number itself.

Comment: This is micro-benchmarking and JSON format is for complex data the best structure (xml has more overhead because of open and close nodes and node names). Sending a number looks like `[53.52598895]` or `{data:53.52598895}` what as `plain/text` is just `53.52598895`. So what is the real issue here, that you thingink about this?

Comment: HTTP is a text protocol. If transfer efficiency is what you're after you can probably look into keeping a socket open. After all each request in HTTP has the request headers which are significantly longer than the few bytes you will be saving anyway.

Comment: If you need to send large amounts of json in the least number of bytes you could look at gzipping the response.  It works pretty much out of the box in php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043284/how-to-get-send-gzip-content-as-php-response

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks! :)